# How to count number of activities in a getstream feed?

Tags: getstream-io

Does getstream provide a way to retrieve the number of activities within a feed?  I have a notification feed setup.  I can retrieve the activities using paginated `get`.  However, I would like to display the number of items within the feed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, there is no API endpoint to retrieve the amount of activities within a feed.

Comment: Do you know whether this is still the case as of 2021?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no way to count activities directly. You can try

- Use a custom feed and use reactions. So now you call count from reactions.
- Other way is store in your app (cache/db/etc).

It worked for me:

```
signature = Stream::Signer.create_jwt_token('activities', '*', '<your_secret>', '*')

uri = URI("https://us-east-api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/enrich/activities/?api_key=<api_key>&ids=<id1,id2,...>&withReactionCounts=true")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
req['Stream-Auth-Type'] = "jwt"
req['Authorization'] = signature

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

puts JSON.parse(res.body)
```

References:

[Retrieve](https://getstream.io/docs/#retrieve)

[reactions_read-feeds](https://getstream.io/docs/#reactions_read-feeds)

[activities](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#activities)

[ruby client](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-ruby/)

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2022

You can only get the number of activities in groups within aggregated or notification feeds. Flat feeds are still not supported.
[Source](https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/node/flat_feeds/)

The best solution is to store important numbers in the database which Stream provides.
[Source](https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/node/collections_introduction/)